# neo4j fulltext index search with special charcters

Tags: neo4j, cypher, fulltext-index

We are using neo4j version 4.1.1,
and we have a graph that represents a structure of objects. 
we support translation using nodes for translation and the connection between an object and a translation node is the object name and description.
for example:
(n:object)-[r:Translation]-(:ru)

means that on relationship r is the name and description of object n in russian.
In order to search by name and description we implemented a fullText index like that:

`CALL db.index.fulltext.createRelationshipIndex("TranslationRelationshipIndex",["Translation"],["Name","Description"], { eventually_consistent: "true" })`

We also support search for items in order to do it we are using the index to query and we have names like "UFO41.SI01V03":

`CALL db.index.fulltext.queryRelationships('TranslationRelationshipIndex', '*FO41.SI0*') YIELD relationship, score` 

but for names as shown above([0-9.*]) no results are returned
while results are returned for name like "*ab.or*"

Is there any one who knows how to make it work? I've tried all 46 analyzers available.
I know we can solve it just using `match()-[r]-() where r.Name contains "<string>"`
but we prefer a more efficient index-using solution to this problem.

stay safe!
and thanks in advance.

p.s if needed I can supply a few lines to recreate it locally just ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The analyzer will probably recognise words like `ab.or` differently than `ab.or123` and consider them a single token in the first case and two tokens in the second case.

There is no analyzer that will really fit your needs except than creating your own.

You can however replace the `.` in your query with a simple `AND`, for eg :

```
CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes('Test', replace("*FO41.SI0*", ".", " AND "))
```

Will return you the results you're looking at.

---

Resources for creating your own analyser :

https://graphaware.com/neo4j/2019/09/06/custom-fulltext-analyzer.html

https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/extending-neo4j/full-text-analyzer-provider/